# J2EE - Do we require transaction management support for anything other than Database?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, transactions, weblogic, application-server

As we know , one of the major difference between web server and application server is **transaction management**. What exactly the transaction management refers. Does it mean the Database transaction support?. Database is external entity , we can use Database with Web server as well as Application server.
So , other than Database entity, do we require transaction management support for any thing else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes transaction management applies to other concepts such as  JMS (and queues generally)

You can find more information on jms and transactions on the java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncgl.html#bncgs).

Another example that is outside of the application server domain are the transactions regarding the [azure service bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-transactions).

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle docs:
"Transaction management contract is used for outbound communication from WebLogic Server to Enterprise Information Systems (EISes)".

For Weblogic, you must create datasource specifing name, jndi-name, driver, host, port, user, password and type of transaction that you need (XA or not XA).
XA transaction is global, not-XA local.

To learn more, see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/resadapter/transact.html